# symfony create a table with attribute from multiple entities

Tags: symfony, mappedsuperclass

I have different entities like:
Element, Status, Action, Contributor ...

And I need to create an entity, let say Synonym, which can be related to one of these previous entities

My entity Synonym, can be a synonym of the entity Element or Status or Action ...

I try to use a MappedSuperclass but I'm really lost.

I think this kind of relation is common and must be easy to create with doctrine but I can't find the good way.

Comment: you could just create table synonym with N foreign keys (ManyToOne relationship). Each relationship is to different entity (element, status, action, contributor, ...)

Comment: can your class hierarchy be defined like this 

class Synonym {}
class Element extends Synonym {}

or Element, Status,.... are some sort of a parent to Synonym?

Comment: Don't use a MappedSuperclass, but a Table Inheritance. So you will have a unique ID column for all of your tables. Then you just have to relate it with the parent table.

Comment: I have create a table as proposed by Miro...